# Use NLog with AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlog

I managed to set up a target to send email using gmail (http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Using_NLog_with_GMail) so I thought it would have been easy to modify it to use AWS SES but... it doesn't work and I don't know why. I tried to set throwExceptions="true" but nothing is logged.

My target reads:

```
<target name="mail" type="Mail" smtpServer="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" smtpPort="465" smtpAuthentication="Basic" smtpUsername="USERNAME" smtpPassword="PASSWORD" enableSsl="true" from="verifiedemailaddress" to="smyemailaddress"/>
```

Anyone managed to set a target so to send log via Amazon Web Service SES SMTP?

Comment: Any fix for this?  I'm running into the same issue.  Was using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to email through SES, and everything worked great, but now I'm trying to go through NLog using exact same credentials, options, etc, and no error message appears, no e-mail arrives, just silently fails...

Answer (score 2):

Try using port 587 instead.
Also, make sure you have verified your sender address with SES. If your account is still in sandbox mode, you will also have to verify each recipient address.
Please keep in mind that you might hit sending ratio limits (1 mail/second in sandbox mode) using this approach.

Hope that helps